# Sound in Layouts

Tags: android

I am developing a guitar app, actually I am trying to make two layouts play different sounds when I "swipe" from one layout to another.
Currently, this layouts play sounds on `ACTION_DOWN`, but stops when I release my finger, not when I move my finger out of this layout's area.

My java:

```
public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootView);
        LinearLayout firstlayout =     (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.firstlayout);
        LinearLayout secondlayout =     (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.secondlayout);
        final MediaPlayer aPlayer;
        final MediaPlayer bPlayer;
        aPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(DisplayActivity.this, R.raw.a);
        bPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(DisplayActivity.this, R.raw.b);
        firstlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // action when on touch action is down pressed
                        aPlayer.start();
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN, location:x" + x + ",y:" +     y);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // action when on touch action is moving
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE, location:x" + x + ",y:" +     y);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // action when on touch action is up
                        aPlayer.release();
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP, location:x" + x + ",y:" + y);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
        secondlayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX();
                float y = event.getY();
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // action when on touch action is down pressed
                        bPlayer.start();
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_DOWN, location:x" + x + ",y:" +     y);
                        return true;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        // action when on touch action is moving
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_MOVE, location:x" + x + ",y:" +     y);
                        return true;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        // action when on touch action is up
                        bPlayer.release();
                        Log.d(TAG, "ACTION_UP, location:x" + x + ",y:" + y);
                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/filename"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.android.appname.DisplayActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/firstlayout"
    android:layout_width="374dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/filename" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/secondlayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/filename" />

</LinearLayout>
```

What do I need to change to make my layouts play sounds like a guitar strings in a guitar app? (without releasing finger play different sounds)
Any help will be appreciated.